# Weird iPhone entry in Connections

Tags: gnome, 17.10, panel, statusbar

In Ubuntu 17.10, from some time to now I see a new weird iPhone entry in my top bar's status menu (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBJTv.png)) 
My questions are:

1) Why did this show up? I don't own an iPhone nor have ever used an iPhone to connect to internet

2) How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Possibly a iPhone broadcasting a hotspot near you?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did think about that.. but since it showed, this displays no matter where I'm at.. It was probably a broadcasting stuff but now is there and I can't delete it